# Unknown column '' in 'where clause'. Error mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Segue abaixo o código que estou usando para tentar fazer um sistema de login, porém está falhando

Código:

```
<?php
   
$link = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome= $nome AND senha = $senha") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    
    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($link) <= 0)
    {
        header("Location:../inicio.php");
    }else
    {
        echo
        "
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            alert('nome de usuário e/ou senha incorretos');
            window.location.href='../index.php';
        </script>
        ";
    }

?>
```

Mensagem aparecida:
**Unknown column 'teste_bot' in 'where clause'**

Nota 1 - eu coloquei diretamente no banco de dados um usuário com nome e senha chamados *'teste_bot'*

Nota 2 - ***se eu colocar '$nome' e '$senha' recebe o seguinte erro -Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /storage/ssd1/516/14288516/public_html/SQL/logar.php on line 10***

Comment: Os campos `$nome` e $senha` não deveria estar entre apóstrofos? `'$nome'` e `'$senha'`.

Comment: Se eu colocar isso da erro

Answer (score -1):

Primeiro, como está salvo este campo de nome e senha no seu banco?
segundo, coloque $nome e $senha entre aspas simples '$nome' '$senha' é o padrão para funcionar
terceiro, corrija isso if(mysqli_num_rows($link) <= 0
dessa maneira a validação está errada, pois não faz sentido o numero de resultados ser <= 0 e ele te levar para a pagina de inicio o certo é if(mysqli_num_rows($link) >= 1 ou, inverta as ordens, se a query te retornar <= 0 coloque o alerta alert('nome de usuário e/ou senha incorretos'); e no else envie ele para a pagina logada

código corrigido:

```
$link = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nome = '$nome' AND senha = '$senha'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

  if(mysqli_num_rows($link) >= 1){
    //loga o usuário
  }else{
    //erro ao logar
  }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]